onclick function argument is changing to different value during printing
i see some strange thing in onclick java script function. i am trying to pass 001364027 number in function argument and trying to print in JavaScript function. but it printing different number 387095. Does anyone know why is it printing different number?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onclick Event</h2>
<h1>HTML DOM Events</h1>
<h2>The onclick Event</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction(001364027)">Click me</button>

JavaScript:
function myFunction(numberin) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World --     "+numberin; 
} 

Hello World -- 387095
it suppose to print same number what it passed in argumnet.

In 001364027 the leading 0 prefix signifies this is in octal. And (oct) 001364027  === (dec) 387095

Put it in quotes to make it a string. myFunction('001364027')
